# Hide widget on page

Tags: widgets

How can I hide a widget from a certain page (one page). After spending an hour, all I can find is with the plugins. The problem is, that I know with them how to do it, but one widget (ad widget) is placed inside my theme panel not like a drag/drop widget, so I cant set it up with widget.

This is my code of widget which i need to hide on one page. Any solution how to do it ?

```
<?php if(get_option('gd_leader_ad')) { ?>

            <div id="leader-wrapper">

                <?php if(get_option('gd_logo_loc') == 'Small in navigation') { ?>

                                       <div id="ad-728-small">
                        <?php echo get_option('gd_leader_ad'); ?>
                    </div><!--ad-728-small-->

                <?php } else if(get_option('gd_logo_loc') == 'Large below navigation') {  ?>
                    <div id="ad-728">
                        <?php echo get_option('gd_leader_ad'); ?>
                    </div><!--ad-728-->


                <div id="logo-large">
                        <?php if(get_option('gd_logo_large')) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_option('gd_logo_large'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo-large.png" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></a>
                        <?php } 
                    </div><!--logo-large-->?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div><!--leader-wrapper-->
```

Comment: Simply wrap the widget in a `if(!is_page('PAGE ID OR NAME'))` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good with php. Do i add it before <?php of before div ? Do i need to add the closing as well, if yes how the whole code which i need to add looks like?

Comment: Just change this line `<?php if(get_option('gd_leader_ad')) { ?>` to `<?php if(get_option('gd_leader_ad') && !is_page('PAGE ID OR NAME OF THE PAGE YOU WANT TO EXCLUDE')) { ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet. Just make sure you change the widget id :

```
<?php
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'widget_display', 50, 3 );
function widget_display( $instance, $widget, $args ){
    if ( is_page() && $widget->id == 'text-39' ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $instance;
}
?>
```

The easiest way is to use a WordPress plugin though. There are lots of free plugins on the directory. I would highly recommend Widget Options : https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/ . Check the image below for integration preview.

[image: Hide widget on page]

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

Simply search & activate plugin "Widget Logic" from wordpress dashboard--> plugins, which creates "Widget logic" section to let you place some conditions for individual active widgets

`!is_page('home');` home-->Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug

Place above code in "Widget logic" section, which display respective widget in all pages except "home" page.